# Privacy Considerations of Widow(er)

Tags: publishing, privacy

The general rule for putting family information up on public family trees such as Ancestry, FamilySearch, your own website, etc., is that no information about living people should be included. This is both a privacy consideration and acknowledgment that you do not have the rights to make available someone else's personal information without their explicit permission.

Data about people who are deceased is considered to be allowable. However, I do see some mitigating circumstances. For instance, I would not include information about a deceased child if one or both parents are still alive. That would infringe on the privacy of the parents.

But a more difficult consideration is for a widow or widower. The widow or widower would certainly be privatized, and no information about that person should be shown.

Are there any published privacy guidelines that state whether a person's partner who has died should also be privatized? Do these guidelines state that information about a living person's deceased spouse infringe on the privacy or rights of the widow(er)?

Comment: Good question, but I wonder as currently stated it is a bit too opinion-based (and I could see it reasonably being closed as such). To get well sourced answers rather than just opinion, perhaps it would be better to frame the question in terms of looking for published guidelines/standards on the subject.

Comment: "This is both a privacy consideration and acknowledgment that you do not have the rights to make available someone else's personal information without their explicit permission." It's also a legal issue under the GDPR if the living person is resident in the EU.

Comment: I think it at least partly depends on the information source - published obituaries often include information about living family, but there should be no issue, e.g., linking to such obits.  If the obit information is republished elsewhere, esp. in another form (such as a family tree), privacy guidelines would seem to apply.

Comment: You could take the approach of the Dutch archives, where "Civil registration (burgerlijke stand) certificates are only allowed for publicaton after a certain period of time. Death certificates after 50 years, marriages after 75 years and births after 100 years", or simply, anyone who is born within the last 100 years should be treated as private.